# In Pokémon Go remote raids, where is the weather determined?

Tags: pokemon-go

When raiding in *Pokémon Go*, inviting people remotely is possible. This means that it's possible to have, for example, the host boosted by one weather type with remote people having different weather types.
Weather boost for local raids means that the level of the raid boss is 25 rather than 20.

**What determines the weather boost when catching the raid boss?**

Is it local or remote weather, i.e. the host or the client? Something else maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on personal experience, as well as mentioned [here](https://pokemongo.fandom.com/wiki/Weather) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/hs79u5/weather_boost_remote_raids_the_original_location/), the weather is based on the location of the remote gym and not your current location.